# With DES, is ECB encryption mode equivalent to CBC with null IV for short data blocks?

Tags: cbc, des, ecb

I got to this by experimentation, but can someone maybe provide an explanation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `CBC` mode processed as $c_i = E_k(p_i \oplus c_{i-1})$ with $c_0 = IV$
- The `ECB` mode processed as $c_i = E_k(p_i)$

If you set **the first block** with $$c_o = IV = 0$$ in the `CBC` mode, than it is calculated as $$c_1 = E_k(p_1).$$ This is exactly as `ECB` mode.

**The next blocks**, however, will not be equal;

- in `ECB` mode $$c_i = E_k(p_i)$$
- whereas in `CBC` mode $$c_i = E_k(p_i \oplus c_{i-1}) \neq E_k(p_i) \text{ for } 1 < i \leq m$$ where $m$ is the number of blocks.

Therefore the equality is only valid for the first block.

Comment: Exactly as I suspected, thank you for a more formal explanation <3